# I wish I could correlate an "inline view"

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax, derived-table, inline-view

I have a Patient table:

```
PatientId   Admitted
---------   ---------------
1           d/m/yy hh:mm:ss
2           d/m/yy hh:mm:ss
3           d/m/yy hh:mm:ss
```

I have a PatientMeasurement table (0 to many):

```
PatientId   MeasurementId   Recorded            Value
---------   -------------   ---------------     -----
1           A               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     100
1           A               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     200
1           A               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     300
2           A               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     10
2           A               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     20
1           B               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     1
1           B               d/h/yy hh:mm:ss     2
```

I am trying to create a result set that resembles:

```
PatientId   Numerator   Denominator
---------   --------    -----------
1           1           1
2           1           1
3           0           1
```

Essentially, a patient will have a 1 in the numerator if the have at least one value for measurement A and one value for measurement B.  In this example, patient 1 has 3 A measurements and 2 B measures, so the numerator is 1.  Patient 2 has 2 A measurements, but no B measurements, so the numerator is 0.  Patient has neither an A measurement nor a B measurement, so the numerator is 0.

My query thus far is:

```
SELECT  PatientId, CASE WHEN a.cnt+b.cnt>2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Numerator, 1 Denominator
FROM    patient p

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  PatientId, count(*) cnt
    FROM    PatientMeasurement pm
    WHERE   MeasurementId='A'
    --AND   Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted)
    GROUP BY PatientId
) a ON p.PatientId=a.PatientId

LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT  PatientId, count(*) cnt
    FROM    PatientMeasurement pm
    WHERE   MeasurementId='B'
    --AND   Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted)
    GROUP BY PatientId
) b ON p.PatientId=b.PatientId
```

This works as expected as long as I don't include the correlated, date restriction (Recorded < dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted).  Unfortunately, correlating an 'inline view' in this manner is not syntactically valid.

This has forced me to re-write the SQL to:

```
SELECT  PatientId, CASE WHEN v.a+v.b>2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Numerator, 1 Denominator
FROM    (

    SELECT  PatientId,
    (
        SELECT  PatientId, count(*) cnt
        FROM    PatientMeasurement pm
        WHERE   PatientId=p.PatientId
        AND MeasurementId='A'
        AND Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted)
        GROUP BY PatientId
    ) a,
    (
        SELECT  PatientId, count(*) cnt
        FROM    PatientMeasurement pm
        WHERE   PatientId=p.PatientId
        AND MeasurementId='B'
        AND Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted)
        GROUP BY PatientId
    ) b
    FROM    Patient p
) v
```

My question: Is there a better, more-efficient way to do this?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
WITH GroupPatients AS 
    (SELECT MeasurementID, PatientId, Count(*) AS cnt
    FROM PatientMeasurement AS pm
    INNER JOIN Patient p ON pm.PatientID = p.PatientID
    WHERE
        MeasurementId IN ('A', 'B')
    AND
        Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted)
    GROUP BY MeasureMentID, PatientId)

SELECT p.PatientID, Case
    When IsNull(GPA.cnt, 0) > 0 AND IsNull(GPB.cnt, 0) > 0 Then 1
    Else 0
End AS Numerator, 1 AS Denominator
FROM Patient p
LEFT JOIN GroupPatientsA AS GPA ON p.PatientID = GPA.PatientID AND GPA.MeasurementID = 'A'
LEFT JOIN GroupPatientsB AS GPB ON p.PatientID = GPB.PatientID AND GPB.MeasurementID = 'B'
```

I've made one tweak to the business logic too - your spec says Numerator should be one if a patient has both A and B measurements - however, your clause of a.cnt+b.cnt>2 will erroneously return one if either a.cnt or b.cnt are 3 or more and the other is zero.

Comment: CodeByMoonlight's approach: 00:00:32.  Winner!

Thanks for the help and the correction.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  p.*, 
        CASE WHEN
        EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    PatientMeasurement pm
        WHERE   pm.PatientID = p.ID
                AND pm.Type = 'A'
                AND pm.Recorded <= DATEADD(hh, 12, p.Admitted)
        ) AND EXISTS (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    PatientMeasurement pm
        WHERE   pm.PatientID = p.ID
                AND pm.Type = 'B'
                AND pm.Recorded <= DATEADD(hh, 12, p.Admitted)
        ) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    Patient p
```

Comment: It's currently missing the date range

Comment: Quassnoi's approach: 00:00:57

Comment: I added the date range in my testing.

Thanks a lot for your help.  Great technique.

Comment: EXISTS is very useful. I'm a bit surprised my query came out quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution can be close to your original attempt using `OUTER APPLY`:

```
SELECT  PatientId, CASE WHEN a.cnt+b.cnt>2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END Numerator, 1 Denominator 
FROM    patient p 
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT      count(*) cnt 
    FROM        PatientMeasurement pm 
    WHERE       MeasurementId='A' 
    AND       Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, p.Admitted) 
    AND pm.PatientId = p.PatientId
) AS a(cnt)     
OUTER APPLY ( 
    SELECT      count(*) cnt 
    FROM        PatientMeasurement pm 
    WHERE       MeasurementId='B' 
    AND       Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, p.Admitted) 
    AND pm.PatientId = p.PatientId
) AS b(cnt)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Sql 2005 or 2008, the entire query can be simplified using some window functions and a pivot:

```
with pData as
(
    select  count(*) over(partition by PatientId, MeasurementId) as cnt,
            PatientId, MeasurementId
    from    PatientMeasurement pm
    where   MeasurementId in('A','B')
    and     Recorded <= dateadd(hh, 12, Admitted)
)
select  PatientId, coalesce([A],0) as cntA, coalesce([B],0) as cntB,
        case when coalesce([A],0) + coalesce([B],0) > 2 then 1 else 0 end as Numerator,
        1 as Denominator
from    pData
pivot   (max(cnt) for MeasurementId in([A],[B])) pvt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @TimeSlot int;
SET @TimeSlot = 12;

WITH 
pt AS (
    SELECT p.PatientID, p.Admitted, m.MeasurementID, m.Recorded,
        CASE 
          WHEN m.Recorded <= dateadd(hh, @TimeSlot, p.Admitted) THEN 1 
          ELSE 0 
        END AS "InTimeSlot"
    FROM Patient AS p
    LEFT JOIN PatientMeasurement AS m ON p.PatientID = m.PatientID
),
cntA AS (
    SELECT PatientID, count(*) AS "A_count"
    FROM pt WHERE MeasurementID='A' AND InTimeSlot = 1
    GROUP BY PatientID
),
cntB AS (
    SELECT PatientID, count(*) AS "B_count"
    FROM pt WHERE MeasurementID='B' AND InTimeSlot = 1
    GROUP BY PatientID
),
cntAB AS (
    SELECT p.PatientID
          ,coalesce(a.A_count, 0) AS "A_cnt"
          ,coalesce(b.B_count, 0) AS "B_cnt"
    FROM Patient as p
    LEFT JOIN  cntA  AS a ON p.PatientID = a.PatientID
    LEFT JOIN  cntB  AS b ON p.PatientID = b.PatientID
),
cntN AS (
    SELECT PatientID,
        CASE WHEN A_cnt > 0 AND B_cnt > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS Numerator
    FROM cntAB 
)
SELECT PatientID, Numerator, 1 AS Denominator FROM cntN
```